# Как сделать редирект с двумя GET?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

```
RewriteRule ^a/([a-z,0-9,-]+)?$/?$ /games.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Так не работает, как будет правильно?)

Например:
Как сейчас:`/games.php?id=5&url=game`
Как нужно: `a/5/game`

Comment: Пример нескольких входящих урлов и их целей при переадресации можно в вопрос добавить?

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение в вопросе не имеет смысла! И чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно видеть какие урлы приходят от пользователя и какие должны получиться после преобразования. Что не понятно?

Comment: То есть, такую ссылку `a/5/game` пришедшую от пользователя надо направить на файл `games.php` в таком виде `/games.php?id=5&url=game`?

Comment: Да, именно так нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/a\/(\d+)\/(\w+) games.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Поправил правило.

Comment: Работает первый вариант. Спасибо.